# Swift: How to DRY Decodable-parsing of an awkward but regular JSON structure

Tags: swift, decodable

Our json-over-rest(ish) API follows a pattern of encoding URLs accessible from a particular object in a list format, under the `@links` key. Made-up example:

```
{ "id": "whatever", 
  "height_at_birth": 38,
  "@links": [
    { "name": "shield-activation-level",
      "url": "https://example.com/some/other/path" },
    { "name": "register-genre-preference",
      "url": "https://example.com/some/path" }
  ]
}
```

On the Swift side we use phantom types and optionality for type-safety. For instance the above json might correspond to a struct like:

```
struct Baby {
    let id: String
    let heightAtBirth: Int
    let registerGenrePreference: Link<POST<GenrePreference>>
    let shieldActivationLevel: Link<GET<PowerLevel>>?
    let magicPowers: Link<GET<[MagicPower]>>?
}
```

The phantom types ensure that we can't post a feeding schedule to the `registerGenrePreference` URL by accident, and the optionality indicates that a well-formed `Baby`-json will always contain an `@links` entry for `registerGenrePreference` but that the other two links might or might not be present. So far so good.

I would like to use `Decodable` to consume this json format, ideally with a minimum of `init(decoder:Decoder)` custom implementations. But I am stumped by the `@links` entries.

I think I see what this would look like if I do the entire decoding by hand:

1. get the baby's container,
2. from it get a nested unkeyed container for the `@links` key
3. iterate over its values (which should be `[String:String]` dicts) and build a dict matching names to URLs
4. for each link `Baby` expects, look it up in the dict (and throw if the property was non-optional and the link is missing)

But steps 2 and 3 are the same for every class following this pattern (not ideal) and even worse, having to do this also prevents me from using the compiler-provided `Decodable` implementation so I also have to manually decode *all the other* properties of `Baby`.

If it helps I'm perfectly happy restructuring `Baby`; one obvious step that might help would be:

```
struct Baby {
    let id: String
    let heightAtBirth: Int
    let links: Links

    struct Links {
        let registerGenrePreference: Link<POST<GenrePreference>>
        let shieldActivationLevel: Link<GET<PowerLevel>>?
        let magicPowers: Link<GET<[MagicPower]>>?
    }
}
```

And of course I expect we'll have to add coding keys, even if only for the snake/camel-case conversion and the `@`:

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case id
    case heightAtBirth = "height_at_birth"
    case links = "@links"
}
```

I could probably make a manual `Decodable` conformance for `Baby.Links`, following the pattern above, but that still will mean repeating the "get the unkeyed collection, transform it to a dict, look up coding-keys in the dict" steps once for each class following this pattern.

Is there a way to centralise this logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following pattern gives me complete type-safety, and most of the implementation lives in the one-off utility class `UntypedLinks`. Each model class needs to define a nested class `Links` with a custom `decode(from: Decoder)`, but the implementation of those is completely boilerplate (probably can be automated with simple code-generation tooling) and reasonably readable.

```
public struct Baby: Decodable {
    public let id: String
    public let heightAtBirth: Int
    public let links: Links

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case heightAtBirth = "height_at_birth"
        case links = "@links"
    }

    public struct Links: Decodable {
        let registerGenrePreference: Link<POST<GenrePreference>>
        let shieldActivationLevel: Link<GET<PowerLevel>>?
        let magicPowers: Link<GET<[MagicPower]>>?

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case registerGenrePreference = "register-genre-preference"
            case shieldActivationLevel = "shield-activation-level"
            case magicPowers = "magic-powers"
        }

        public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let links = try UntypedLinks<CodingKeys>(from: decoder)
            registerGenrePreference = try links.required(.registerGenrePreference)
            shieldActivationLevel = links.optional(.shieldActivationLevel)
            magicPowers = links.optional(.magicPowers)
        }
    }
}

public class UntypedLinks<CodingKeys> where CodingKeys: CodingKey {
    let links: [String: String]
    let codingPath: [CodingKey]

    class UntypedLink: Codable {
        let name: String
        let url: String
    }

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        var links: [String: String] = [:]
        while !container.isAtEnd {
            let link = try container.decode(UntypedLink.self)
            links[link.name] = link.url
        }
        self.links = links
        self.codingPath = container.codingPath
    }

    func optional<Phantom>(_ name: CodingKeys) -> Link<Phantom>? {
        return links[name.stringValue].map(Link.init)
    }

    func required<Phantom>(_ name: CodingKeys) throws -> Link<Phantom> {
        guard let link: Link<Phantom> = optional(name) else {
            throw DecodingError.keyNotFound(
                name,
                DecodingError.Context(
                    codingPath: codingPath,
                    debugDescription: "Link not found")
            )
        }
        return link
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best I've got so far, but I'll gladly accept an alternative answer if it improves on this one.

Comment: (Turns out it's not too difficult to add `Encodable` support either. I ended up using `Mirror` to avoid repeating the list of links _yet again_.)

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a well defined structure for your links. They are a dictionary `[String : String]` so you can use that to your advantage in using Decodable.

You may want to consider setting up your structs like below. The links are decoded from the JSON, and an extension provides your optionality of the exact links you are looking for.

A Linkable protocol could be used to add the conformance to any class/struct that needs it.

```
import Foundation

struct Link: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let url: String
}

protocol Linkable {
    var links: [Link] { get }
}

extension Linkable {
    func url(forName name: String) -> URL? {
        guard let path = links.first(where: { $0.name == name })?.url else {
            return nil
        }

        return URL(string: path)
    }
}

struct Baby: Decodable, Linkable {
    let id: String
    let heightAtBirth: Int
    let links: [Link]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case heightAtBirth = "height_at_birth"
        case links = "@links"
    }

    static func makeBaby(json: String) throws -> Baby {
        guard let data = json.data(using: .utf8) else {
            throw CocoaError.error(.fileReadUnknown)
        }

        return try JSONDecoder().decode(Baby.self, from: data)
    }
}

extension Baby {
    var registerGenrePreference: URL? {
        return url(forName: "register-genre-preference")
    }

    var shieldActivationLevel: URL? {
        return url(forName: "shield-activation-level")
    }
}

let baby = try Baby.makeBaby(json: json)
baby.registerGenrePreference
baby.shieldActivationLevel
```

Comment: Thanks for the fully-worked-out answer! Unfortunately this loses all the type-safety guarantees we want from the links. It's easy to get _some_ of them back (the `URL` properties in the `Baby` extension can be functions `func shieldActivationLevel() -> Link<GET<PowerLevel>>?`) but not (easily) the guarantee "`Baby` json must provide this particular link otherwise it is malformed and no `Baby` should be decoded".